# Freeswitch mod_python No module named freeswitch

Tags: python, freeswitch

I installed Freeswitch 1.6 in Debian 8, using [this](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Debian+8+Jessie) link. Installing latest release branch section.

Module python is enabled using fs_cli:

```
>module_exists mod_python                                                                                              
true
```

**Symptoms**

When I execute my Python script I get:

```
    2016-08-05 05:49:23.875318 [ERR] mod_python.c:231 Error importing module
    2016-08-05 05:49:23.875318 [ERR] mod_python.c:164 Python Error by calling script "fax": <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>    
    Message: No module named freeswitch    
    Exception: None    
    Traceback (most recent call last)
File: "/usr/share/freeswitch/scripts/fax.py", line 1, in <module>
```

Using [this](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_python#Cannot_import_freeswitch) document:

**Troubleshooting:**

1. This same script is working with other Freeswitch box.
2. Moved file properly:

   `ls -al /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
   freeswitch.py`
3. Script fax.py content is [here](http://pastebin.com/mamZiXkq)
4. Reboot Freeswitch
5. Script freeswitch.py location

   - /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/freeswitch.py
   - /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freeswitch.py
   - /usr/share/pyshared/freeswitch.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied `freeswitch.py` to `/usr/share/freeswitch/scripts/`
and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to copy `freeswitch.py` to `.../freeswitch/scripts/`

Comment: This duplicates the original answer almost verbatim. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute. You can show your support for an original answer by upvoting.